# Cassandra keyspace fails when using symbolic link

Tags: cassandra, symlink

**Need**: create keyspace on alternate device

**Problem**: service aborts on startup with dir-create failure messages below.

`INFO  [main] 2017-01-06 00:45:03,300 ViewManager.java:137 - Not submitting build tasks for views in keyspace system_schema as storage service is not initialized`

`ERROR [main] 2017-01-06 00:45:03,393 Directories.java:239 - Failed to create /var/lib/cassandra/data/opus/aa-15be7240d3db11e6ad0eed0a1d791016 directory`

`ERROR [main] 2017-01-06 00:45:03,397 DefaultFSErrorHandler.java:92 - Exiting forcefully due to file system exception on startup, disk failure policy "stop"`

**Context**: Cassandra 3.9 single-node ubuntu 16.04; directory perms are below.

```
01:52 opus/ cd /var/lib/cassandra/data
01:52 opus/ ls -l
total 24
drwxr-xr-x  3 cassandra cassandra 4096 Jan  6 00:41 opus
drwxr-xr-x 24 cassandra cassandra 4096 Jan  5 23:49 system
drwxr-xr-x  6 cassandra cassandra 4096 Jan  5 23:50 system_auth
drwxr-xr-x  5 cassandra cassandra 4096 Jan  5 23:50 system_distributed
drwxr-xr-x 12 cassandra cassandra 4096 Jan  5 23:50 system_schema
drwxr-xr-x  4 cassandra cassandra 4096 Jan  5 23:50 system_traces

01:52 opus/ cd opus
01:52 opus/ ls -l
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 3 cassandra cassandra 4096 Jan  6 00:41 aa-15be7240d3db11e6ad0eed0a1d791016
```

when the link is installed

```
01:57 data/ ls -l
total 20
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root      root        35 Jan  6 01:57 opus -> /media/opus/quantdrive/opus
```

**Steps**:

1. Vanilla install of cassandra 3.9;
2. Create keyspace in cqlsh `create keyspace opus with replication = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1 };`
3. Create table `use opus; create table aa(aa int, primary key(aa));`
4. Stop cassandra
5. Move keyspace dir `mv /var/lib/cassandra/data/opus /media/opus/quantdrive`
6. Create symbolic link `ln -s /media/opus/quantdrive/opus /var/lib/cassandra/opus`
7. Start cassandra [FAILS AS ABOVE] with create directory, when directory already present

No change in perms on `opus` keyspace directory, I just moved it.  When I move it back, cassandra starts fine.

I would be grateful for any help with this and I apologize in advance if I the solution to my problem is described elsewhere or if I'm missing the obvious.

Answer (score 0):

**Move the mount point for the target drive from a `user-owned` directory to a `root-owned` one.** I moved the mount-point in my case from `/media/opus/quantdrive` which is owned by user `opus` to `/mnt/quantdrive` which is owned by `root` and everything worked fine.